Hide/show button on password not working in Vue 3 composition API
I'm trying to implement a show/hide password button in vue 3 composition API. When I click on the button it toggles both view/hide for both password box and confirm password box.
This is my code
Vue Playground

I've been able to solve the problem and my code is fully working now.
The problem I was having all along was, using ConfirmPassword in the ternary statement instead of password. There is is no input type called confirmPassword that was why it didn't work
This is the link to the solution  Vue Playground
